# CSS grid - remove elements with jQuery so they don't take up space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a css grid layout with "boxes" inside, that I filter with a text input and javascript. How can I hide the filtered out elements so that they don't even take up space within the grid (so the shown elements slide to the front) with jQuery?

```js
jQuery.expr[':']['contains-insensitive'] = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
var $box = $('.box');
$('#search').on('input', function(e) {
  $box.show();
  $('.title').filter(`:not(:contains-insensitive('${this.value}'))`).closest('.box').hide();
});
```

```css
.content {
         display: grid;
         grid-gap: 20px;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr) ) ;
          background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content">
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="title">John</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="title">Jack</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="title">Jane</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="title">Jenny</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: use display none and filter them using specific class name

Comment: That doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this work you need to hide the `a` elements that wrap the `.box`, not just the `.box`. Try this:

```js
jQuery.expr[':']['contains-insensitive'] = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

var $a = $('.content a');
$('#search').on('input', function(e) {
  $a.show().find('.title').filter(`:not(:contains-insensitive('${this.value}'))`).closest('a').hide();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content">
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">John</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">Jack</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">Jane</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">Jenny</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Instead of hiding `.box` elements hide their parents (`a`)

```js
jQuery.expr[':']['contains-insensitive'] = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
var $box = $('.box');
$('#search').on('input', function(e) {
  $box.parent().show();
  $('.title').filter(`:not(:contains-insensitive('${this.value}'))`).closest('.box').parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content">
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">John</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">Jack</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">Jane</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">Jenny</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this does not display all items again when removing a value from the search box

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the `.box` divs, hide the parent `a` tag.

```js
jQuery.expr[':']['contains-insensitive'] = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
var $a = $('a');
$('#search').on('input', function(e) {
  $a.show();
  $('.title').filter(`:not(:contains-insensitive('${this.value}'))`).closest('a').hide();
});
```

```css
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr) ) ;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content">
    <a>
        <div class="box">
            <p class="title">John</p>
            Other content.
        </div>
    </a>
    <a>
        <div class="box">
            <p class="title">Jack</p>
            Other content.
        </div>
    </a>
    <a>
        <div class="box">
            <p class="title">Jane</p>
            Other content.
        </div>
    </a>
    <a>
        <div class="box">
            <p class="title">Jenny</p>
            Other content.
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```